# Wildcard in Jenkins to get Current date in DD-MM-YY format and append to a file name

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, wildcard

I am running the JMeter script in Jenkins. After the execution I am sending an email with attachment. Attached is the screenshot.
The file attached has Date in its name as I run this script everyday. Only Date which is in **DD-MM-YY** format will be changed everyday. How to make this wildcard in Attachments field dynamic for Date part.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use [Build Timestamp plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-timestamp/). But use v1.0.1 as there's an unfixed bug introduced i  v1.0.2.

Set the preferred format in the Jenkins configure page,then

`[  **/TestResults${BUILD_TIMESTAMP}.csv  ]`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible in freestyle projects or you will have to use another plugin like [Filesystem List Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/filesystem-list-parameter-plugin/) in order to return the "newest" file in the given directory

Alternatively you should be able to achieve this using [Pipeline](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-test-jenkins-pipeline-tutorial):

```
def timestamp = new Date().format('dd-MM-yyyy')
emailext attachmentsPattern: '**/TestResults' + timestamp + '.csv', body: 'kindly find results enclosed', subject: 'results', to: 'johndoe@example.com'
```